# Does such an entire function exist?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist an entire function $f\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $\Re(f(x+iy))=e^{-y}\sin x+e^{2y}\cos x$? If so, how to find all such $f$?

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy-Riemann Equations?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $f=u+iv$ is holomorphic, then $u$ is harmonic, i.e. $\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=0$.